# How is persistent disk use determined in GCP Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

In the pricing section, Google says that there is a default amount of PD per worker (varies depending on batch vs streaming). I am running a job, and the amount of persistent disk use is much higher than it should be, given the number of workers that I have (compared to the default PD use). This is consistent across multiple distinct jobs. What is causing the increased PD use? For reference, the default is 480 GB for a streaming worker, but I am getting charged for 5888 GB.

Comment: What is your job ID?

Comment: @jkff 2017-07-12_13_02_25-18120989511327716317. The part I am confused about is "Current PD" - compared to what the pricing page says the PD should be for four streaming workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update as of 2021**

Dataflow now has Streaming Engine - streaming engine does NOT rely on persistent disks to hold state for streaming jobs - instead it provides a 'service' that abstracts streaming state/snapshot storage.

If Disk billing is a concern in your streaming pipelines, consider using streaming engine.

See more information: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#streaming-engine

---

This is a streaming pipeline with autoscaling enabled.

According to https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#autoscaling:

*Streaming pipelines are deployed with a fixed pool of persistent disks, equal in number to --maxNumWorkers*

According to https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#persistent-disk-resources:

*The default size of each persistent disk is 250 GB in batch mode and 400 GB in streaming mode.*

So the expected value of "Current PD" should be around (your value of `maxNumWorkers`) * 400GB, rather than 4 * 400GB.

Comment: Hi @jkff this is a pretty big let down, is there some technical reason for this, why can't the disk scale up and down with the workers or just as space is needed?

Comment: We are working on improvements to the streaming runner pushing it more in the "serverless" direction, not unlike https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/07/life-of-a-cloud-dataflow-service-based-shuffle (for batch pipelines), that will address this limitation.